# Detecting Overlapping Mailing Addresses

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to identify overlapping ranges in this dataset but have encountered difficulties when attempting to consider a 3rd set ('Main Street' column) in my sample dataset below.

I've started removing duplicates from my CSV using Pandas' *duplicated*:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Main_Street.csv')
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['street_name', 'start_range', 'end_range'], keep=False)]
```

I am then looking to incorporate what I've learned with only 2 sets of ranges, here.  I've looked at "intersect" but I'm not sure that allows for a 3rd set of data?

```
x = range(1, 10)
y = range(8, 20)
list(set(x) & set(y))

Output: [8,9]
```

**Dataset**

[image: Dataset_Addresses]

The desired output would to show that Main Street 850-850 overlaps Main Street 800-899

Comment: Provide some [mcve]. How are you reading this dataset? What issues are you having with converting the code you showed to actual code that solves this problem?